# How to create declaration file for library entrypoint

Tags: typescript, npm

I write an npm library that consists of multiple ES6 modules, which are then bundled into 1 js file. The structure is as following:

```
src
  main.ts
  one.ts
  two.ts
  three.ts
  types
    index.d.ts
index.ts
```

index.ts file imports main.ts and exports it, this is the entrypoint for library.

When I create bundle d.ts files are automatically created for each file and put nearby like

```
two.ts
two.d.ts
```

I see in other libraries there is just 1 index.d.ts file for library entrypoint, how can I achieve declaration file be generated only for entrypoint and not for each separate es6 module?

Another question, I keep all my interfaces in separate file and just import them when I need them. Like:

```
import { someInterface } from './types'

const something: someInterface
```

This creates another problem, these imports go to autogenerated d.ts files like this:

```
import { someInterface } from './types';
declare class someClass {
    someVar: string;
}
```

I want someInterface to just be included as text, not as import.

Or am I doing everything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured everything out, in order to make 1 d.ts file gor library entrypoint a separate npm package is needed, I used `dts-bundle-generator`

In order to run it from webpack after original d.ts files are generated for every module I used `webpack-shell-plugin-next`

Usage:

```
// webpack.config.js
    
...
plugins: [
    new WebpackShellPluginNext({
      onBuildEnd: {
        scripts: ['node ./node_modules/.bin/dts-bundle-generator -o dist/myLib.d.ts src/main.ts'],
        blocking: false,
        parallel: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
...
```

This generates 1 d.ts file for library entrypoint.

As for imported interfaces, they need to be imported and exported from `main.ts` so that d.ts generator can put them into file as text, not as import.